# Using pandas in Python to export a user input string split into multiple rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, string, split

I have a column in Excel that has ~11,500 rows that I'm using to format code to put into a SAS formatting code. Unfortunately, many of the rows have apostrophes in the text, so it is throwing off the added apostrophes I formatted in Excel when I copy it over.

I thought about the problem and thought why not strip the excess apostrophes in Python; I ran into a similar problem with the apostrophes interfering with Python, but I was able to work around this by making the string an input. Up to my conditional statement, everything works as expected -- I input multiple words with apostrophes and it returns them without.

At this point, I want to export the apostrophe-stripped results back to Excel (I'm aware that I could copy and paste, but I don't want to risk losing any data). I was also able to do this using pandas; the problem is that when I define my data to export, it puts all of the data into one cell in one row, whereas I want the data returned in the original ~11,500 rows. I tried using .split, but with no success, so I'm sure that isn't the way to go about it. Any suggestions?? See below:

```
#Apostrophe Remover

#Ask user to input the desired text as var1
MyString=str(input("Enter Text Here: "))

#Define var2 as an apostrophe
MySubstring="'"

#Search for apostrophes in entry and remove if applicable; state if not applicable

if MySubstring in MyString:
    MyString = MyString.replace("'", "")
    print()
    print(MyString)
else:
    print()
    print("No apostrophes found!")

#Creating string split by commas as var3    
MyStringSplit=MyString.split(',')
print(MyStringSplit)
    
#Export Python Output to Excel
import pandas as pd

data = {'ICD-10 Code & Description': [MyStringSplit],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ICD-10 Code & Description'])

df.to_excel (r'C:/Users/tjm4q2/Desktop/TM Thesis DX Codes Python Output.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = {'ICD-10 Code & Description': [MyStringSplit],
        }
```

I believe you just need to remove the square brackets around `MyStringSplit` since it is already a list. `.split()` returns a list of strings.
Because it's already a list, you are creating a single row in pandas when including the square brackets:

[image]

Instead you want

```py
data = {'ICD-10 Code & Description': MyStringSplit,
        }
```

[image]

BTW, you don't even need to define your `data` dictionary, instead you could delete that entire line and simply do:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(MyStringSplit, columns = ['ICD-10 Code & Description'])
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver, I've been working on this for two hours -- who knew I was just two brackets away :'(

Comment: @TrevorM Sometimes I like to test dataframes and misc code snippets in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) because you can simply run `display(df)` to get an output like my screenshot above. Of course you can always print them, but jupyter notebook or colab can be faster and more convenient to test in.